# No actual for constant interface in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I have the following entity, core, containing one of my components, generator. I pass generator a signal that is made from the sum of the generic m_r of core and the signal start of core.

However upon trying to compile this, I get the error  `error: no actual for constant interface "m_r"` pointing me to the line `generator_imp : generator`. I assume it has something to do with start_generator being composed of m_r, however even after googling for a few hours, I have been able to find very little related to this specific problem. Has anyone encountered something like this before?

File the error stems from:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.my_components.all;

entity core is
  generic (
    m_r : unsigned(31 downto 0)  := x"00000001";
    step  : unsigned(31 downto 0)
  );
  port (
    clk              : in std_logic;
    reset            : in std_logic;
    start            : in unsigned(31 downto 0);
    f                : out std_logic
  );
end core;

architecture arch of core is

  signal start_generator       : unsigned(31 downto 0) := x"00000000";
  signal n                     : std_logic;

begin

  start_generator <= m_r + start;

generator_imp : generator
  generic map(
    step  => step
  )
  port map(
    clk               => clk,
    start             => start_generator,
    reset_in          => reset,
    padded_message    => padded_chunk,
    n                 => n
  );

end arch;
```

my_components package:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package my_components is


    component generator is
        generic (
          step  : unsigned(31 downto 0)
        );
        port (
          clk                 : in    std_logic;
          start               : in    unsigned(31 downto 0);
          reset_in            : in    std_logic;
          padded_message      : out   std_logic_vector(511 downto 0);
          n                   : out   unsigned(31 downto 0)
        );
    end component;
end package my_components;
```

Additionally, the entity core is generated within another component "all" using a for generate loop, as described below. It is also part of the my_components package, but for the sake of keeping this code overseeable I have removed it after thouroughly checking that all port names in the component match the entity. The for-generate loop works like below:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.my_components.all;

entity all is
  port (
    clk : in std_logic
  );
end all;

architecture Behavioral of all is

  constant count : integer := 5;
  type f_array is array (0 to count -1) of std_logic;
  signal f_signals : found_array;

  signal reset         : std_logic := '0';

  signal start         : unsigned(31 downto 0) := x"11111111";
begin

  generate_cores : for I in 1 to mining_core_count - 1 generate
    core_imp: core
      generic map(
        m_r => to_unsigned(I,32),
        step  => to_unsigned(count, 32)
      )
      port map(
        clk           => clk,
        reset         => reset,
        start         => start,
        f             => f_signals(I)
      );
  end generate;

  core_zero : core
  generic map(
    m_r => x"00000000",
    step  => to_unsigned(count, 32)
  )
  port map(
    clk           => clk,
    reset         => reset,
    start         => start,
    f             => f_signals(0)
  );

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: you dont show the component declaration of `generator`. The error implies you havent connected `m_r`.

Comment: I advise against using `all` as an entity name, as it is a reserved keyword

Comment: @Tricky Thanks for the comment, I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be cause by the fact that signal 'start_generator' is an arithmetic operation on a concurrent part? This could cause this signal be seen as non-constant or stable as an input port.
Just thinking loud..

Comment: Thanks for your answer domilo, however I've resolved the issue now by basically deleting and recloning my project and copying my edited files over. I assume it was some sort of cache issue, unfortunately.